# Is there any way to add more trace information and I can see them in the run history entries

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I am trying to debug a complex logic implemented in a Logic App workflow.

This question is inpiered by my C# programming background.

Is there any way to add more trace information and I can see them in the run history entries ?

**Update 1**

I am looking for a way to add debug trace messages like "At this point variable V1 is '12'"

I am using Run history since it is the most available debugging tool for me. Is there any way to get above trace message in the run history view?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yupp, [you can configure Azure Monitor logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/monitor-logic-apps-log-analytics) for your Logic App:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for help. I added more clarification to my question. Can you please take a look.